# PHP functions strpos() and stristr()

Tags: php

I need to create search box, but with strpos function are problems. When I type , for example,  name Jane, then there are no result, searchResult array is empty, but when I type ane (Without first character), it's working. Function stristr is working without that problem, but I need to use strpos().
Here is my code, I have 3 files: index.php, script.js, server.php.

```
//index.php


<?php

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Profit | Homework | AJAX</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="inp">
    <div class="result"></div>
</body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>


//script.js


$(".inp").on("input", function(){
    let val = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "server.php",
        data: {value: val},
        success: function(r) {
            r = JSON.parse(r);
            console.log(r);
            $(".result").empty();
            r.forEach(function(i){
                $(".result").append(`<div> <h1> ${i.name} </h1> <h2> ${i.surname} </h2> <img src="${i.img}" width="200" heigth="200"> </div>`)
            })
        }
    })
})


//server.php

<?php
    class Search {
        function __construct(){
            $this->arr = [["name" => "Jane", "surname" => "Brown", "img" => "img/manager-1.png"],
                    ["name" => "Bob", "surname" => "Crown", "img" => "img/Business-Man-Clipart-PNG-Image.png"],
                    ["name" => "Mike", "surname" => "Ford", "img" => "img/lending-img.png"]];       

            $this->searchResult = [];

            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
                $searchText = $_POST["value"];
                if (strlen($searchText) != 0){
                    foreach ($this->arr as $value) {
                        if (strpos($value["name"], $searchText) || strpos($value["surname"], $searchText)){
                            $this->searchResult[] = $value;
                        }
                    }
                }
                print json_encode($this->searchResult);
            }
        }
    }

    $x = new Search;
?>
```

Comment: The function you're looking for is `stripos`

Comment: Does this have anything to do with JavaScript?

Comment: @VLAZ I tagged languages, that I use

Comment: You simply need to go read the manual for strpos, there is an explicit “Warning” on that page explaining what you are currently doing wrong: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: @Narek that doesn't mean those languages are relevant to the question, though. If you are only asking for PHP, it's useless to add other stuff.

Comment: @Narek  why don't you used `in_array()`, simple one liner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the strict comparison in such case,

```
if (strpos($value["name"], $searchText) !== false || strpos($value["surname"], $searchText) !== false){
```

I added a strict comparison with `false`. Should work.